# Please help me with this numerical

Tags: architecture, computer-science

A 32 bit 87654321 in hexadecimal is stored at location 1000. What is the value of byte in address 1002 if the system is Big-endian? Also find same if system is in Little-endian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal number `87654321` in hexadecimal is `05397FB1`. We have the following 4 bytes: 05, 39, 7F, B1. In big endian it would be stored as:

```
Address:  Value:
1000      05
1001      39
1002      7F
1003      B1
```

In little endian it would be stored as:

```
Address:  Value:
1000      B1
1001      7F
1002      39
1003      05
```